# Time Limit Exceeded error when submitting c++ code on Leetcode

Tags: c++

I am solving a leetcode problem, the code works fine when I ran it, but when I submitted the code I got a Time Limit Exceeded error. I double checked the code but didnt find any infinite loop.  Can anyone please take a look for me.

Below is the leetcode problem description:

We have an array A of integers, and an array queries of queries.

For the i-th query val = queries[i][0], index = queries[i][1], we add val to A[index].  Then, the answer to the i-th query is the sum of the even values of A.

(Here, the given index = queries[i][1] is a 0-based index, and each query permanently modifies the array A.)

Return the answer to all queries.  Your answer array should have answer[i] as the answer to the i-th query.

Example 1:

Input: A = [1,2,3,4], queries = [[1,0],[-3,1],[-4,0],[2,3]]
Output: [8,6,2,4]
Explanation: 
At the beginning, the array is [1,2,3,4].
After adding 1 to A[0], the array is [2,2,3,4], and the sum of even values is 2 + 2 + 4 = 8.
After adding -3 to A[1], the array is [2,-1,3,4], and the sum of even values is 2 + 4 = 6.
After adding -4 to A[0], the array is [-2,-1,3,4], and the sum of even values is -2 + 4 = 2.
After adding 2 to A[3], the array is [-2,-1,3,6], and the sum of even values is -2 + 6 = 4.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> sumEvenAfterQueries(vector<int>& A, vector<vector<int>>& queries) {
        vector<int> B;

        for(int i = 0; i < queries.size(); i++)
        {
            int index = queries[i][1];
            A[index] = A[index] + queries[i][0];
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < A.size(); j++)
            {

                if(A[j]%2 == 0)
                {
                    sum = sum + A[j];

                }
            }


            B.push_back(sum);
        }

        return B;
    }
};
```

Comment: If you are sure the code is correct and works on your end, then have you considered optimizing your code? Time Limit Exceeded means simply that--your code is too slow. It matters not whether your program terminates.

Comment: A TLE error usually means you need to rethink your algorithm.

Comment: I think you could do this: The fastes way to check if a number is even or odd is to check whether the last bit is 1 or 0. You can probably google how to do that

Comment: @Hemil That won't matter here because the OP has the wrong algorithm anyway, and it is probably already optimized by the compiler.

Comment: @hemil that is premature optimization -- the compiler is perfectly free to choose the fastest way to test `A[j] % 2 == 0`.  It's also not the reason this program is exceeding the time limit.

Answer (score 3):

You are likely exceeding the time limit because your algorithm is naive.  By recomputing the sum for every query, your program has a time complexity of O(M * N), where M is the size of the array, and N is the number of queries.

It's almost a guarantee that the test set will be designed to fail (by exceeding time limit) on a naive implementation.

There is absolutely no need to recompute the sum every time.  You only need to compute it *once*.

After that, every time you have a query, you just need to update the current sum using only what *changed*.  Use your program's knowledge of the previous and new values (*i.e.* part of the sum or not) when updating.

By doing this, your program's time complexity becomes O(M + N).